# BioPython: Residues size differ from position

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, protein-database

I'm currently working with a data set of PDBs and I'm interested in the sizes of the residues (number of atom per residue). I realized the number of atoms -len(residue.child_list) - differed from residues in different proteins even though being the same residue. For example: Residue 'LEU' having 8 atoms in one protein but having 19 in another!

My guess is an error in the PDB or in the PDBParser(), nevertheless the differences are huge!

For example in the case of the molecule 3OQ2:

```
r = model['B'][88]
r1 = model['B'][15] # residue at chain B position 15

In [287]: r.resname
Out[287]: 'VAL'
In [288]: r1.resname
Out[288]: 'VAL'
```

But

```
In [274]: len(r.child_list)
Out[274]: 16
In [276]: len(r1.child_list)
Out[276]: 7
```

So even within a single molecule there's difference in the number of atoms. I'd like to know if this is normal biologically, or if there's something wrong. Thank you.

strong text

Comment: ask https://www.biostars.org/

Comment: Can you post an example? I've being using Bio.PDB parser for ages and I can tell it's reliable for PDB files. Try testing r.is_disordered() to detect disordered atoms (atoms in alternate location in PDB) or list(r).

Comment: I tried for r.is_disordered() for both residues and the result was '0' for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at the PDB provided and the difference is really the fact that for the first VAL (88) there are atomic coordinates for Hydrogens (H) whereas for the other VAL (15) there isn't.

```
ATOM   2962  N   VAL B  88      33.193  42.159  23.916  1.00 11.01           N  
ANISOU 2962  N   VAL B  88     1516    955   1712     56   -227   -128       N  
ATOM   2963  CA  VAL B  88      33.755  43.168  24.800  1.00 12.28           C  
ANISOU 2963  CA  VAL B  88     1782   1585   1298    356    -14    286       C  
ATOM   2964  C   VAL B  88      35.255  43.284  24.530  1.00 12.91           C  
ANISOU 2964  C   VAL B  88     1661   1672   1573   -249      0   -435       C  
ATOM   2965  O   VAL B  88      35.961  42.283  24.451  1.00 14.78           O  
ANISOU 2965  O   VAL B  88     1897   1264   2453     30   -293     21       O  
ATOM   2966  CB  VAL B  88      33.524  42.841  26.286  1.00 12.81           C  
ANISOU 2966  CB  VAL B  88     1768   1352   1747    -50   -221   -304       C  
ATOM   2967  CG1 VAL B  88      34.166  43.892  27.160  1.00 16.03           C  
ANISOU 2967  CG1 VAL B  88     2292   1980   1819   -147     73     -8       C  
ATOM   2968  CG2 VAL B  88      32.020  42.727  26.586  1.00 17.67           C  
ANISOU 2968  CG2 VAL B  88     2210   2728   1774   -363   -401     83       C  
ATOM   2969  H   VAL B  88      33.642  41.425  23.899  1.00 13.21           H  
ATOM   2970  HA  VAL B  88      33.340  44.035  24.608  1.00 14.73           H  
ATOM   2971  HB  VAL B  88      33.941  41.979  26.492  1.00 15.37           H  
ATOM   2972 HG11 VAL B  88      34.011  43.670  28.081  1.00 19.23           H  
ATOM   2973 HG12 VAL B  88      35.110  43.912  26.983  1.00 19.23           H  
ATOM   2974 HG13 VAL B  88      33.777  44.746  26.959  1.00 19.23           H  
ATOM   2975 HG21 VAL B  88      31.902  42.523  27.516  1.00 21.20           H  
ATOM   2976 HG22 VAL B  88      31.596  43.562  26.377  1.00 21.20           H  
ATOM   2977 HG23 VAL B  88      31.647  42.026  26.047  1.00 21.20           H
```

I would go about filtering out these atoms for every residue in analysis. Then you should almost always get the same number of atoms. As someone mentioned the other thing you have to consider is what Biopython call 'disordered residues'. These are residues for which you have more than one alternative location for the atoms in the crystal lattice (they call this 'altloc'). Sorting this out should solve your problem. 
Let me know if you need help with filtering out these atoms.
Fábio